# Cassandra EC2 All host(s) tried for query failed

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I have my cassandra instance running on AWS EC2.
I created a Spring boot app on my local system, where I am trying to connect to this db and query for data.
Everytime I am getting the error:

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All
>   host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /aaa.zz.yy.xx:9042

In my spring boot app these are the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I am creating my connection like this:

```
@Bean 
    public Session session() {
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().withPort(9042).addContactPoint("aaa.zz.yy.xx").withoutJMXReporting().build();
        cluster.getConfiguration().getSocketOptions().setReadTimeoutMillis(60000);
        return cluster.connect(keyspace_name);
      }
```

On my cassandra.yaml file:

```
rpc_address: aaa.zz.yy.xx
rpc_port: 9160
```

I even added an inbound rule in my EC2 where I provided my local system IP (where Spring boot app is running).

What am I doing wrong?

> EDIT: TLDR: What I was doing wrong is that I was using private IP in
>   my code. When I switched to public IP, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rpc_port is thrift port. I assume you are using cql.

Try with `.withPort(9042)` this is native_transport_port.
(Default: 9042) The port where the CQL native transport listens for clients.

Also use the public contact address instead of private one when trying to connect from local m/c.

I am adding my edits here:

1. use public ip address of ec2 in the method: addContactPoint (public ip of EC2 instance is the one that we use in putty for connecting to EC2 for example: ec2-203-0-113-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com)
2. use port 9042 in code : withPort
3. in the yaml file on EC2, rpc:address should be the private ip address

If using Spring Boot, in pom.xml, only 1 dependency is sufficient for cassandra connectivity:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Laxmikant, I did try with 9042, but that is also not working.  When I am using cqlsh on EC2 instance, it is working fine with the same IP

Comment: aren't you using your private ip ? are you able to ping 172.31.43.72 from local ?

Comment: Thank you. You pointed in the right direction. I had to use public ip in my code. It worked

Comment: Edited my answer for sake of completeness . Accept if you agree. Thanks :)